# Is it possible to completely replace a post with an action/filter?

Tags: posts, filters, actions

Currently I am trying to replace the `$post` global with another dynamically loaded post in the `wp` action. However, while even in the templates the correct post data shows when outputting `$post`, the actual output content isn't updated. I backtraced through the entire `the_content` function, but I can't find anything out of the ordinary.

Is this even possible, and if so, what am I missing?

Comment: Changing the `$post` global is not going to help you as anything later on can change the its value. Even the main loop changes the `$post` global. IMHO, you are on the wrong track here

Comment: But I assume WordPress is basing these changes to the value on something, isn't it?

Comment: `$post` by default, if nothing breaks it, holds the first post in the loop of the main query

Answer (score 0):

You can try with using pre_get_posts

add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query');

function alter_query($query) {
    //gets the global query var object
    global $wp_query;

```
//gets the front page id set in options
$front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');

if ( 'page' != get_option('show_on_front') || $front_page_id != $wp_query->query_vars['page_id'] )
    return;

if ( !$query->is_main_query() )
    return;

$query-> set('post_type' ,'page');
$query-> set('post__in' ,array( $front_page_id , [YOUR SECOND PAGE ID]  ));
$query-> set('orderby' ,'post__in');
$query-> set('p' , null);
$query-> set( 'page_id' ,null);

//we remove the actions hooked on the '__after_loop' (post navigation)
remove_all_actions ( '__after_loop');
```

}